# Edit comment in mobile version working unexpectedly

Tags: support, edits, mobile-web

I'm having issues when trying to edit a comment I just made through the mobile version of SO.

When I placed the comment the *edit* link does appear, but I'm not able to press it.
Even though I reload the page completely, the link still appears, but I'm still unable to press it.

Using my phone's optic cursor trying to 'catch' the link is also not possible.

Is this a local problem? It's been like this forever (at least on my side).

I'm using CyanogenMod 7 on my Android phone.

Comment: Is there Mobile Version of SO available? Really

Comment: @PareshMayani Not an app - let's call it browserfriendly if that clears it up ;)

Comment: happened to me too. zoomed in and then it worked (granted, I have an updated browser too xD)

Comment: As a note, it only appears to happen (for me) when the comment makes the "signature and edit link" span to the next line and become just above the "add comment" link. 9 times out of 10 my browser decides "add comment" was the intended target and not the edit link. (Adding a top margin to the add comment link would probably fix it to provide ample separation of the two links.)